# firebase realtime db with mobile sdk works in china?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time, great-firewall-of-china

My mobile game is a real-time game, running intensively on firebase real-time database. Does firebase realtime db work in china? I have not launched it yet in China because of this suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebase rest api for your App in China, see their doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

The idea is to have your web app in China talks to your REST API server outside of China, and the REST API server talks to firebase REST api endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase or any google services are blocked in China dubbed the "Great Firewall of China". You may have to look for other alternatives unless you're happy with using a VPN in China.